# Query to get the line with the latest date

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

`SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T0.[PriceFOB], T0.[PriceAtWH], T0.[DocEntry], T0.[CardCode], T2.[DocDate], T3.[CardName] FROM IPF1 T0 LEFT JOIN OIPF T2 ON T2.[DocDate] = (SELECT MAX(T4.[DocDate]) FROM OIPF T4 WHERE T0.[DocEntry]=T4.[DocEntry]) INNER JOIN OCRD T3 ON T0.[CardCode] = T3.[CardCode] WHERE T3.[GroupCode] = '105'`

I am using the following query listed above.

The issue rises where I have multiple lines of the same item listed but my goal is to get the one with the LATEST DocDate.

If someone can please help and explain what it is that I am doing wrong.

I have tried Order By, Group By but keep getting multiple errors (syntax mostly)

`SELECT ItemCode, PriceAtWH, DocEntry, PriceFOB, CardCode FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T0.[ItemCode] ORDER BY T0.[DocEntry] DESC) AS ROWNUM FROM IPF1 T0) IPF1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1`

This is the other query that I was able to come close to my solution but I need it to filter for only GroupCode = '105' from OCRD matching the CardCode

The Main goal is to filter out a Master DATA which is combined with IPF1 and OCRD(Only need to pull Group Code from this) and to filter the IPF1 with the Group Code first. Then proceed to do the Max Date or Max DocEntry ID for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a distinct to get one row per event even if they have different dates and use the `MAX` on the select

> ```
>     SELECT distinct T0.[ItemCode], 
>            T0.[PriceFOB], 
>            T0.[PriceAtWH], 
>            T0.[DocEntry], 
>            T0.[CardCode], 
>            T3.[CardName], 
>            MAX(T2.[DocDate] ) DocDate
> FROM IPF1 T0     
> LEFT JOIN OIPF T2 
> ON T0.[DocEntry]=T2.DocEntry]
> INNER JOIN OCRD T3 
> ON T0.[CardCode] = T3.[CardCode] 
> WHERE T3.[GroupCode] = '105'
> GROUP BY T0.[ItemCode], T0.[PriceFOB], T0.[PriceAtWH], T0.[DocEntry], T0.[CardCode],T3.[CardName]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

WITH T AS (SELECT T10.[DocEntry], T10.[CardCode], T10.[ItemCode], T10.[PriceFOB], T10.[PriceAtWH] FROM IPF1 T10 INNER JOIN OCRD T11 ON T10.[CardCode] = T11.[CardCode] WHERE T11.[GroupCode] = '105')
SELECT T.[DocEntry], T.[CardCode], T.[ItemCode], T.[PriceFOB], T.[PriceAtWH] FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.[ItemCode] ORDER BY T.[DocEntry] DESC) AS ROWNUM FROM T) T WHERE ROWNUM = 1

So I ended up solving my own problem.

Thank you Julissa for trying buy your query has an error where you are missing a "[" in front of DocEntry and also the query does not do what I want it do, multiple instances of the same item for all date still show up. Thank you for trying!